# Renombrar y combinar columnas Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

Tengo un dataframe (que surge de unir varios .csv) donde tengo 2 columnas "subgrupo" y "Subgrupo", como tendría que hacer para quedarme con una sola columna que contenga los datos completos, ya que en algunos hay nulos.
gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que los datos estén como en las columnas 2 y 3, puedes crear otra concatenando los datos. Ahora, ten en cuenta que si en alguna fila existen datos para ambas columnas, se van a unir.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col2': ['a', np.nan, 'c', np.nan], 'col3': [np.nan, 'b', np.nan, 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Columna nueva
df['col4'] = df['col2'].fillna('') + df['col3'].fillna('')

print(df)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias, me resultó

Comment: @LucasA.Ugartemendia Favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha ayudado